# Why I get merge conflict?

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

I save my changes into stash. Add some code. Commit.

When I try to apply stashed changed I get merge conflict:

```
@@@ -847,45 -846,6 +855,53 @@@ do $$ begin RAISE NOTICE 'Move time: 20
  set local my.sys_time to '2018-08-23';

  do $$ begin
++<<<<<<< Updated upstream
 +do $$ begin RAISE NOTICE 'Move time: 2018-08-23'; end $$ language 'plpgsql';
 +set local my.sys_time to '2018-08-23';
 +
 +do $$ begin
 +--TODO: Test UPDATE when NEW.app_period is same as OLD.app_period
 +-- and NEW.app_period is intersect app_period() for some rows
 +--As update behavior should be same for rows where NEW and OLD
 +-- as different as equal (see next test after this one)
++||||||| merged common ancestors
++--TODO: Test UPDATE when NEW.app_period is same as OLD.app_period
++-- and NEW.app_period is intersect app_period() for some rows
++--As update behavior should be same for rows where NEW and OLD
++-- as different as equal (see next test after this one)
++=======
++>>>>>>> Stashed changes
  RAISE NOTICE 'Test UPDATE app_period by 2018-08-17 .. 2018-08-24, when applicatoin perio
    USING HINT =  'Row just updated. Nothing special should happen';
  end $$ language 'plpgsql';
```

But why? Stashed changes adds nothing to that `commented TODO` lines where conflict occur.

Comment: Git has an algorithm which determines when two simultaneous changes to a source file fires a merge conflict.  It is something like two separate changes within 2-3 lines of each other.  But regardless, when you apply a stash, there is _always_ the chance that you may get a merge conflict.  Come to work hungry when you apply the stash, because you should be ready for this possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't silently assume two immediately adjacent blocks of text are unrelated because they often are related. In another merge your added block would be comments describing a function that was moved elsewhere or factored out.

Answer (score 0):

A conflict means, the file has been changed at least twice, **in a parallel way**. Like a fork:

```
Common ancestor -----> V1
                -----> V2
```

You resolve the conflict by **sequencing the changes**, you put them horizontally in a chronological order:

```
Common ancestor --> (V1 + V2) --> V3
                        |          |
                        |          |
conflicted stated after merge      new state after resolved conflict
```

Which part of the file is changed doesn't matter, the way the file is changed (parallel instead sequential) creates the conflict.